# git log internals: performance using the reverse option

Tags: git

To save me/others delving into the internals, can anyone tell me if the performance of `git log A..B` is any worse when given the `--reverse` option ?

My understanding is that the list of commits are double linked so i would have thought not.

However:

if i use the `-nX` option, `git log -nX A..B` yields X commits from B.

but now if i use `git log -nX --reverse A..B`  i *still get X commits from B albeit in reverse order.

?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Commit "links" are unidirectional<sup>1</sup> but the performance will be basically identical for other reasons.

In particular, the notation `A..B` does not mean "commits from `A` to `B`".  It actually means to compute a set difference: `reachable(B)` - `reachable(A)`, where `reachable()` is the set of commits that is "reachable" starting from a given reference-label.<sup>2</sup>  That is, first git resolves the name to a raw SHA-1, then, for the commit identified by that SHA-1, it finds all of that commit's parents, all of the parents' parents, all their parents, and so on, throughout the entire commit graph.

Although it's slightly more complex (it's done internally and there is a lot of optimization),<sup>3</sup> you can think of `git log` as first running a series of `git rev-list` commands.  If you run:

```
git rev-list A
```

you will get as output the set of all commit IDs (SHA-1s) reachable from label `A`.  If you repeat this for label `B`:

```
git rev-list B
```

you will get the set of all commit IDs reachable from label `B`.  You can then imagine git running both `git rev-list` commands, and then taking away from the 2nd, all the SHA-1 IDs provided by the first, since `A..B` means `B --not A`.

If you use `-n num`, this limits the number of selected SHA-1s to *`num`*; however, as documented in both the [`git log`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html) and [`git rev-list`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-list.html) manuals, this limiting is done

> before commit ordering and formatting options, such as `--reverse`.

You can use `git rev-list A..B` to produce the complete list (in whichever order) and then run it through `head` or `tail`, on Unix-like systems, and supply the resulting SHA-1 values to `git log` (but then you must add `--no-walk` to `git log` since otherwise it again treats each raw SHA-1 as if it means "find every SHA-1 reachable from this one"—this is not terribly well documented).

---

<sup>1</sup>Internally, each commit records its parent commit IDs.  Commits are immutable, so the addition of a new, later commit that refers back to an older, existing commit *cannot* change the existing commit: there is no way to record the "child commit" ID in the parent.  So the links are necessarily reverse-direction only.

<sup>2</sup>The most obvious case where these are very different involves completely-disjoint sub-graphs.  Consider a commit graph such as:

```
x0 <- x1 <- x2 <- x3   <-- label A

y0 <- y1 <- y2         <-- label B
```

Here, label `A` selects all the `x` items, and label `B` selects all the `y` items.  The set of items reachable from `A` remains unchanged regardless of whether or not we subtract the set of `B` items, and vice versa.  So here, `B..A` (aka `A --not B`) is the same as `A`, and `A..B` (aka `B --not A`) is the same as `B`.  With a more conventional, more-linear graph as found in most repositories, we get less surprising (but sometimes still surprising to some) results.  For instance, given:

```
       x   <-- A
      /
o <- o
      \
       y   <-- B
```

(imagine the diagonals as arrows as well, pointing to the `o` node) the result of `A --not B` is node `x`, and the result of `B --not A` is node `y`.  Hence *both* `B..A` *and* `A..B` are non-empty.

<sup>3</sup>In a large graph, finding large sets can take a lot of work, so git is chock full of graph-theory algorithms.

Comment: excellent -more infos than i dared hope for :o ~thx for taking the time :)